# If $R$ is a principal integer domain, then any finitely generated projective $R$-module is isomorphic to $R$

Tags: ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, projective-module

I am trying to prove that if $R$ is a principal integer domain, then any finitely generated projective $R$-module is isomorphic to $R$. To do so, I've fixed $P$ as a finitely generated projective and proved the following:

- There is an epimorphism $f: R^n \rightarrow P$, for some integer $n$. This is quite easy: If $P = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \rangle$, then define $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) := \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i a_i$.
- There is a non-zero morphism $g: P \rightarrow R$. To show this, recall that it follows from $P$ projective that the exact sequence
  $$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}(f) \rightarrow R^n \xrightarrow{f} P \rightarrow 0$$
  splits, hence $f$ is a retraction. Let $h: P \rightarrow R^n$ be the right inverse of $f$. For every $x \in P$, the element $h(x)$ is written as $h(x) = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, and particularly one can define $h_j: P \rightarrow R$ by $h_j(x) = a_j$. Since $h$ is non-zero, there must be some $j$ satisfying $h_j(x) \neq 0$. Take $g = h_j$.

My plan was to show that $g$ is an isomorphism, but I did not found a way to do so. I am in the right track? If so, can anyone point out how do I finish the argument?

Comment: Do you mean "every finitely generated projective $R$-module is isomorphic to $R^n$ for some $n$"? The $\mathbb Z$-modules $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^2$ are not isomorphic. (Also, is $A$ the same as $R$?)

Comment: This cannot be true. For example, $P = R^2$ is not isomorphic to $R$. You probably want to show that any finitely generated projective $R$-module is free. To prove this, you should first show that every submodule of $R^n$ is free. (Do an induction on $n$ and use that $R$ is a principal ideal domain.)

Comment: Maybe the question is wrong, them. I've taken it from an old test my professor applied, so I will check with him. Thank you.
P.S.: I will fix some typos. $A$ is the same as $R$.